# Question about functions and powers

Tags: calculus, functions

If you had a function to the power of (2/2) is that the same as having a function to the power of 1? What if the function is something like (-x^2) would that to the power of (2/2) be the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost true.  Notice that

$$f(x)=(x^2)^{1/2}\stackrel?=x^1$$

But that

$$((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1\ne-1$$

Indeed, this means

$$(x^2)^{1/2}=x\operatorname{sgn}(x)$$

where $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ takes the sign of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Remeber that

1) by definition , $\sqrt X$ is the **positive** number $Y$ such taht $Y^2=X$, so we have:
$$
\sqrt{x^2}=|x|
$$

2) $-x^2$ means $-(x)^2$ so we have $-x^2<0 \quad \forall x \ne 0$ and $\sqrt{-x^2}$ is not a real number for all $x\ne 0$.

3) $(-x)^2=x^2\ge 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $\sqrt{(-x)^2}=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$